# Sql query to extract average grouped by a column

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm trying to generate a SQL query to extract an average montly powerusage (of a year) for an ID.

```
+----+------------+------------+
| id | powerusage |    date    |
+----+------------+------------+
|  1 |        750 | 2011-12-2  |
|  1 |       1000 | 2011-12-1  |
|  1 |       1500 | 2011-11-15 |
|  1 |        100 | 2011-11-13 |
|  1 |         50 | 2011-11-10 |
|  2 |        500 | 2011-11-15 |
|  2 |        200 | 2011-11-13 |
+----+------------+------------+
```

So if ID = 1 I want (avg november + avg december) / 2 = (1750/2 + 1650/3) / 2 = **712.5**

```
select AVG(powerusage) as avgMontlyPowerUsage
from usagetable 
where id = 1 and YEAR(date) = 2011
```

But this will give me 680.

How do I do a average on a group?

**Many thanks for all the answers! But I see my question is incorrect. See updated question**

Comment: And what if you had dates from October and December but not November? Should the sum be divided by 3 or 2 ?

Comment: Is your power data stored daily?

Comment: You probably want to nest queries, in the inner query you group by id and month and calculate the sum. The outer query you group by id and find the avg of the sums on the first query.

Comment: @ypercube: by 2, because only 2 months available.

Comment: @DigitalPrecision: yeah but result it the same?

Comment: @a'r: yes, should be, but could be that there is data missing. E.g. data aggregator offline.

Comment: @PoweRoy: Then try my 2nd query.

Comment: I'm terribly sorry but I see I asked the question wrong I want an average of the montly averages...

Comment: @PowerRoy: Then, just change `sum(powerusage)` to `avg(powerusage)` in ajreal's or Jaydee's or Kevin's answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like

```
select AVG(montlyPowerUsage) from (

SELECT MONTH(date) as mnth,sum(powerusage) as montlyPowerUsage
from usagetable 
where id = 1 and YEAR(date) = 2011 group by MONTH(date)

) t1
```

For Edited question

```
select AVG(montlyPowerUsage) from (

SELECT MONTH(date) as mnth,AVG(powerusage) as montlyPowerUsage
from usagetable 
where id = 1 and YEAR(date) = 2011 group by MONTH(date)

) t1
```

Comment: Thanks. I think ajreal got the same answer as I did a minute earlier

Answer (score 3):

```
mysql> select avg(powerusage) 
from 
(select monthname(date), sum(powerusage) as powerusage 
from usagetable 
where id=1 and year(date)=2011
group by monthname(date)) as avg_usage;
+-----------------+
| avg(powerusage) |
+-----------------+
|       1700.0000 |
+-----------------+
```

```
select avg(total_powerusage) 
from 
(select monthname(date), sum(powerusage) as total_powerusage 
 from usagetable 
 where id=1 and year(date)=2011
 group by monthname(date)
) as avg_usage;

/* the use of subquery 
   is to return total of unique occurrences, 
   and sum powerusage of each occurrence,
   which mean, you just need to apply AVG into the subquery */
```

Answer (score 1):

This should give you monthly averages for every year and user. Some of the syntax may be MS SQL specific, but the logic should be good.

```
SELECT id, AVG(usage), year FROM
(SELECT id, SUM(powerusage) as usage, YEAR(date) as Year, MONTH(date) as Month
  FROM usagetable 
  GROUP BY id, YEAR(date), MONTH(date)) as InnerTable
GROUP BY id, year
```

Comment: It's tagged `MySQL`, not `SQL-Server`

Comment: PS. Remove the last group by "year" and the year selector if you just want all time monthly averages

Comment: it should be pretty much the same code. I just don't have a mysql db on hands to try the inner select syntax

Answer (score 0):

Try adding a group by on the id

```
GROUP BY id
```

Or the date, whichever suits.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT SUM(powerusage) / (MONTH(MAX(`date`)) - MONTH(MIN(`date`)) + 1)
           AS avgMontlyPowerUsage
FROM usagetable 
WHERE id = 1 
  AND YEAR(`date`) = 2011
```

or (depending on what you need when data is sparse):

```
SELECT SUM(powerusage) / COUNT( DISTINCT MONTH(`date`) )
           AS avgMontlyPowerUsage
FROM usagetable 
WHERE id = 1 
  AND YEAR(`date`) = 2011
```

Warning: Neither of the above is optimized for performance.